# How to create an api in node js that process a few command line arguments whenever it is invoked?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create a resume based on the details of a person that I have in my database. I have access to his basic details, education, work experience,... with me.

There is a GitHub repo called [hackmyresume] (https://github.com/hacksalot/HackMyResume) that creates polished résumés and CVs in multiple formats from your command line or shell. It takes input in JSON format(Fresh Schema) and converts that to Word, HTML, PDF, LaTeX, plain text, and other arbitrary formats.

hackmyresume build resume.json TO out/resume.all -t

Everything works as expected if I follow the instructions in the readme page of the repo. But I would like to replicate this functionality in node API.
Please guide me.

Comment: Try googling `node execute shell command`

Comment: [medium_blog_post](https://medium.com/@colinwren/automating-my-resume-with-hackmyresume-fresh-6b99d655b1a)

Comment: Hey @ChaitanyaSairam, what OS are you using?

Comment: @Terry I'm using Windows 10

Comment: Oh cool, yes me too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work. First you must install hackmyresume:

```
npm install hackmyresume -g
```

Then this can be call with the following Node.js code:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('hackmyresume build resume.json TO out/resume.html out/resume.doc', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(`An error occurred: ${err.message}`);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log(`Result: ${stdout}`);    
        if (stderr) {
            console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        }
    }
});
```

My sample resume.json looks like so:

```
{

    "basics": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "label": "Programmer",
    "picture": "",
    "email": "john@gmail.com",
    "phone": "(912) 555-4321",
    "website": "http://johndoe.com",
    "summary": "A summary of John Doe...",
    "location": {
        "address": "2712 Broadway St",
        "postalCode": "CA 94115",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "countryCode": "US",
        "region": "California"
    },
    "profiles": [{
        "network": "Twitter",
        "username": "john",
        "url": "http://twitter.com/john"
    }]
    },
    "work": [{
    "company": "Company",
    "position": "President",
    "website": "http://company.com",
    "startDate": "2013-01-01",
    "endDate": "2014-01-01",
    "summary": "Description...",
    "highlights": [
        "Started the company"
    ]
    }],
    "volunteer": [{
    "organization": "Organization",
    "position": "Volunteer",
    "website": "http://organization.com/",
    "startDate": "2012-01-01",
    "endDate": "2013-01-01",
    "summary": "Description...",
    "highlights": [
        "Awarded 'Volunteer of the Month'"
    ]
    }],
    "education": [{
    "institution": "University",
    "area": "Software Development",
    "studyType": "Bachelor",
    "startDate": "2011-01-01",
    "endDate": "2013-01-01",
    "gpa": "4.0",
    "courses": [
        "DB1101 - Basic SQL"
    ]
    }],
    "awards": [{
    "title": "Award",
    "date": "2014-11-01",
    "awarder": "Company",
    "summary": "There is no spoon."
    }],
    "publications": [{
    "name": "Publication",
    "publisher": "Company",
    "releaseDate": "2014-10-01",
    "website": "http://publication.com",
    "summary": "Description..."
    }],
    "skills": [{
    "name": "Web Development",
    "level": "Master",
    "keywords": [
        "HTML",
        "CSS",
        "Javascript"
    ]
    }],
    "languages": [{
    "language": "English",
    "fluency": "Native speaker"
    }],
    "interests": [{
    "name": "Wildlife",
    "keywords": [
        "Ferrets",
        "Unicorns"
    ]
    }],
    "references": [{
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "reference": "Reference..."
    }]

}
```

This will output .html and .doc formats. It's easy to add others or just pass in OUT resume.all and it will generate in all formats.

If you want to wrap this in an API, I'd suggest adding an Express POST method that accepts a body of resume.json.

Comment: @Tery I resolved the issue using your solution. Thank you so much!!
As u mentioned i created an POST API that accepts a body of resume.json, but i'm unable to get this tool to work without storing the resume.json file in a temp location of working directory. Any ideas by making use of the file object received in node and make it work?
[Link](https://github.com/hacksalot/HackMyResume/issues/226) to github issue i posted in hackmyresume repo

Comment: @ChaitanyaSairam, it would be nice if you could write the output to stdout, this way you could avoid writing the temporary file. I don't know of any way to do this however.. you might be able to use a named pipe perhaps, but I don't know if this would work!